# Who is the father in Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

Spoilers Ahead!

In the movie *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*, Wanda mentions that she is a happy mom in so many other universes to those same two children, Billy and Tommy.

Is there any mention in the movie as to who the father is? Because in the prime universe Wanda was with Vision and if that were to have happened in all the other universes, she couldn't have had kids. The only way to have kids would have been like in the comics, through magic. But then in the prime universe, Wanda could have had those kids by magic without moving to another universe and taking over the life of another Wanda.

So, the question is, who is the father of Billy and Tommy in all the universes?

Comment: Just bad writing. It makes no sense there is an alternate universe where those kids are real.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Had they said, there is that "one" universe where the kids were real, then it could still work. Perhaps even explain her obsession. And in that universe Wanda met another man.

Comment: If the multiverse is of infinite variety,  then "many" is a small number in comparison

Comment: @BCdotWEB Many Worlds Interpretation theory would disgaree. Hugh Evrett III's idea is that there would be infinate of every combination of every universe at some point. Fringe (TV series) also played with this concept, except it also added the idea of "iterations" of inextrcibly linked pait of universes where humanity was trying to break a cycle of both universes dying.

Comment: Simon Williams?

Comment: Have you seen WandaVision ?

Comment: @iandotkelly - if we take WandaVision into account, things only get more messy. Her artificial kids, Billy and Tommy, in the prime universe are some how real children in other universes. Sure we can say her dreams of the other universes made her conjure up Billy and Tommy in the prime, but that only increases the importance of the real father. I'm trying to see if the film hinted on anything.

Comment: @HorusKol - the way Wanda explains it, it appeared that it was in almost every other universe. In any case, that doesn't affect the question.

Comment: @MovieMe Who's to say the 838 kids are real and weren't created form a spell by Wanda there? We know she also has magic.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, the movie makes it clear that Tommy and Billy are not confined to just 838. For all those kids in all those universes, one logical explanation is _magic_. What stops Prime-Wanda from having kids through magic as well? (given that might actually be the only way if there is no father)

Comment: That's just a plot hole, like so many others in this film.

Answer (score 15):

### Sadly, Billy and Tommy were never real in *WandaVision*

[The two children in *WandaVision* are creations of Wanda's reality-altering magic](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Scarlet_Witch#Sudden_Pregnancy), as is the Vision in that series. As such the *WandaVision* are not real 'children' have no 'father'.

### So where did they come from?

What we learn in *Dr Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* is that [Wanda's dreams of the children are actually reflections of real children of other variants of Wanda in other universes](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Scarlet_Witch#Searching_for_her_Children). The children of *WandaVision* are therefore the product of that subsconscious knowledge.

### The movie avoids drawing any attention to the identity of the father

The variant of Wanda in the 838 universe actually really lives in WestView with her two real children. Their father never appears in the movie, is never mentioned, and provides no childcare when Wanda leaves them unattended having been possessed by the dreamwalking Scarlet Witch from our universe. *There seem to be no family photographs at all in Wanda's house in WestView.*

[image: Wanda's house in WestView]

As *Wanda* actress Elizabeth Olsen [explains](https://collider.com/elizabeth-olsen-doctor-strange-2-vision-pietro-comments-multiverse-of-madness/):

> “... there is this multiverse, and in the version of the universe this woman wasn't with Vision. We liked having that be a mystery. For some reason **he's not in her world**. I always thought of her as more of a domestic Wanda. **They got divorced. They're separated. She's not wearing a wedding band for a reason.** Like those kinds of things. We liked the idea of her being on her own. The idea really is that the most important thing once you become a mother in the world are your children, and that's why.”

### Are the children magical creations or natural procreations?

Olsen's remarks tend to suggest that these children were naturally conceived with a human father, who is no longer on the scene.

[There is precedent in the Marvel Comics for the children to be magical creations](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/William_Maximoff_(Earth-616)), but this would call into question the Scarlet Witch's overall strategy in *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*. If the creation of magical children is possible anywhere in the MCU multiverse, why doesn't the Scarlet Witch use her collosal magical powers, the Darkhold, and her multiversal knowledge to do this, rather than stealing the children from another Wanda?

Comment: The _real father_ idea and that _it doesn't matter who he is_ works only if it was an isolated universe where she had kids. But Wanda mentions and shows that she has kids most of the multiverses. That makes it look like Vision and she were together only in the Prime Universe and perhaps a few other. This automatically makes the father an important person. Which is why I was looking to see if the movie hinted at who it might have been.

Comment: Agent Coulson, you sly dog. RIP.

Comment: @EleventhDoctor while it may not be relavent to the over all plot of Dr. Strange 2, it may matter in terms of either Wanda long term and/or now that Marvel has opened itself up to a multi-verse anything from anywhere from anywhen could potentially be relavant down the line. I also agree with MovieMe that if they made a point that these boys exists in multiple universes, than "how" they exist is surely a point of contention and may actually be about something yet to be revealed for Wanda down the line.

Comment: @MovieMe I apologise for the dismissive tone of my original answer. I have updated with a much more serious consideration of the *magical children* theory and comments from Elizabeth Olsen herself that cast just a little light on this for us. Hope you like!

Comment: Given the age of the children in the movie, the boys birth date would have been close to the events of the Age of Ultron in 616. How closely the timelines map and how Wanda came to be in the US (and in Westview) is arguable, but it suggests the father would have been around in her Sokovian days.